# chart clicker daily vs. hourly

Tags: perl, charts

I am using the [perl chart clicker module](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egphat/Chart-Clicker-2.86/lib/Chart/Clicker.pm) to generate a chart based on hourly usage. It seems to be working pretty well. [image]
I am providing the data like:

```
sub createcch {
  my ($keys,$name) = @_;
  my @lh = (1..@{$keys});
  my $am = Chart::Clicker::Data::Series->new(
    keys => \@lh,
    values => $keys,
    name => $name,
    range => $range,
  );
}

#$data contains series generated by the sub
my $ds = Chart::Clicker::Data::DataSet->new(series => [$data]);
```

I have a cosmetic issue of how the data looks on the chart and I haven't found a way to correct it. Can I change the X axis to list the data in weeks or days instead of hours, without compromising the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating your dataset ($ds), you have to create a chart and context objects.  Then you can edit those axis 'labels', without changing the data view.

```
    my $dataSets = Chart::Clicker::Data::DataSet->new( series => \@datasets, );
    $chart->title->text($name);
    $chart->title->padding->bottom(5);
    $chart->add_to_datasets($dataSets);
    my $context = $chart->get_context('default');

    $context->range_axis->label('Counts');  # side
    $context->range_axis->format('%d');

    $context->domain_axis->label($bottom);  # bottom
    $context->domain_axis->format('%s');
    $context->domain_axis->tick_labels(\@Lables);
    $context->domain_axis->ticks($cnt);
```

You should create a sub-routine for building the @Labels array with what you'd prefer to see - because it will likely be dynamic.  The ..axis->format('%s') performs something like a printf() conversion on the scalars stored in the @Lables array, so it's important this matches the contents.

See [Chart::Clicker::Context](http://search.cpan.org/~gphat/Chart-Clicker-2.86/lib/Chart/Clicker/Context.pm) for more details.

Comment: That was a lot easier than I thought. Their documentation is not very good but the module is. Thanks for the help.